# DatePicker wont show date after selection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker

I'm trying to make a fragment that takes away few things:

Date

Weight

Height

Notes

For now I got stuck with the datePicker.
I managed to make the dialog appear but when i chose a date it force closes  the app.
I want it to take the date I picked and show it in this label

> : dd/mm/yy

Tried to look forward to other questions but none of them helped me.
Hope you can :)
Here is the Fragment:

```
public class NewTracker extends Fragment {


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtracker, container, false);

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("מעקב חדש");
    EditText dateSelect = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.dateSelect);
    dateSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });

}


}
```

Here is the datepicker fragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, day);

    EditText edittext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dateSelect);
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    edittext.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Here is the error log.

```
Error:
04-26 15:12:47.022 14245-14245/com.example.matancohen.sg50 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.matancohen.sg50, PID: 14245
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.matancohen.sg50.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.java:40)
                                                                                 at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:171)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:175)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Error log after ahmad's solution:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.matancohen.sg50, PID: 23173
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.matancohen.sg50.NewTracker.<init>(NewTracker.java:43)
                                                                             at com.example.matancohen.sg50.Tracking$1.onClick(Tracking.java:41)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

When i click OK after choosing a date it gives me a Force Crash
what can I do?
thank you!

Comment: Can you post the log of error?

Comment: `getView().findViewById(R.id.dateSelect);` your DatePickerDialog has to contain `R.id.dateSelect` this way. Does it have?

Comment: you get a nullpointerexception because there is no `R.id.dateSelect` in your `DatePickerDialog` i think

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: Edited the question @s

Comment: @VladMatvienko so where should i put it? how do I manage to put the chosen date in the Edit text box?

Comment: It will take too much time to explain, and edit your code. But there are tones of examples of how to use DatePickerDialog on the internet. Just google, pick any and follow.

Comment: Tried it and nothing helped me :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Any of the two ways:

1. Move your `public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment` class implementation inside your fragment.. `NewTracker`

Modify your code to:

```
  public class NewTracker extends Fragment {


    public static EditText dateSelect;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtracker, container, false);
        dateSelect = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.dateSelect);
        dateSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("מעקב חדש");
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(year, month, day);
            String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            dateSelect.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
        }
    }
}
```

2. use a `interface` in your `DialogFragment` to notify the Calling `fragment` after the Date is selected.

Comment: Tried first one and now when i try to get to the NewTracker its Force closing

Comment: Too long.. where to post?

Comment: done , and when I did what you asked me to do I had to move the EditText dateSelect outside the OnViewCreated so the new inner class can call it

Comment: yes `EditText dateSelect` needs to declare global...and initialize it like: `dateSelect = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.dateSelect);`..

Comment: any other solution? :(